# Hooks Keyboard in c#

Tags: c#, hook

I want to use this project to read from my barcode reader behind the scenes.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

By the time I added:

```
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D0);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D1);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D2);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D3);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D4);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D5);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D6);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D7);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D8);
        gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.D9);
```

Just read the code, consisting of 10 numbers, I would use it in my code.
It is like this:

D1

D2

D0

D0

D0

D0

D1

D2

D3

D4

How do I concatenate the numbers?
I'm doing the tests but doesn't works.

Second question:
How do I get the code as above like '0000001234' without char D?

thanks

Comment: You are displaying the virtual key code, as produced by Keys.ToString().  You need to convert it to a *character*.  That's pretty simple for the keys that produce digits, just cast to (char).

Comment: thanks Hans... char cast works fine.
Instead, about chaining how can I?
Would be enough to put an AppendText to textbox instead of Items.Add to listbox...
But, then I do not know how to take the result to work it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend you a different, more efficient way to easily hook your keyboard:

First, use DllImport and PINvoke inorder to import GetASyncKeyState:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);
```

Then, you can just use the above function as you wish, such as:

```
public static bool IsKeyPushedDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey)
{
    return 0 != (GetAsyncKeyState((int)vKey) & 0x8000);
}
```

More info: [PINvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx).

Best of luck.

EDIT: btw, If you want to use a barcode reader, you can also create one of your own, or take a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/e5a17395-ab47-4e8c-ab69-d7cadeed65cb/barcode-reader-integration-with-c) or [here](http://www.barcodelib.com/csharp/barcode_reader_csharp.html).